# C++ Error: "No match for call to"

Tags: c++

I have got problem, without this:

```
std::sort(TargetList, TargetList+targetLoop, CompareTargetEnArray());
```

Everything works fine, but with this line above me, compilating does not work.

```
struct CompareTargetEnArray
{
     bool operator() (TargetList_t & lhs, TargetList_t & rhs)
     {
         return lhs.Distance < rhs.Distance;
     }
};

void Aimbot()
{
TargetList_t * TargetList = new TargetList_t[NumOfPlayers];
int targetLoop = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < NumOfPlayers; i ++)
{
    PlayerList[i].ReadInformation(i);
    if(PlayerList[i].Team == MyPlayer.Team)
        continue;

if (PlayerList[i].Health < 2)
        continue;
//PlayerList[i].Position[2] -= 10;
CalcAngle (MyPlayer.Position, PlayerList[i].Position, PlayerList[i].AimbotAngle);

TargetList[targetLoop] = TargetList_t(PlayerList[i].AimbotAngle, MyPlayer.Position,PlayerList[i].Position);

    targetLoop++; 
}
if(targetLoop > 0)
{
    std::sort(TargetList, TargetList+targetLoop, CompareTargetEnArray());

if (!GetAsyncKeyState(0x2))
    {
        WriteProcessMemory (fProcess.__HandleProcess,(PBYTE*)(fProcess.__dwordEngine + dw_m_angRotation),
                TargetList[0].AimbotAngle, 12, 0);
    }
}
targetLoop = 0;
delete [] TargetList;
```

}

I cannot fix this... only removing this

```
    std::sort(TargetList, TargetList+targetLoop, CompareTargetEnArray());
```

resolves the problem, but 'program' does not work propertly. And do not ask me why I am writing a some kind of aimbot, only for my purposes.
Errors:

```
c:\program files       (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|2287|error: no  match for call to '(CompareTargetEnArray) (TargetList_t&, const TargetList_t&)'

c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|2290|error: no match for call to '(CompareTargetEnArray) (const TargetList_t&, TargetList_t&)'|
```

Comment: Please post the full error message if you can

Comment: Make your `operator ()` member `const`, likewise for the parameter references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functor should be:

```
struct CompareTargetEnArray {
     bool operator() (TargetList_t const& lhs, TargetList_t const& rhs) const {
     //                            ^^^^^                    ^^^^^       ^^^^^
         return lhs.Distance < rhs.Distance;
     }
};
```

Also, please use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: can I ask why it is that?

Comment: Read up on "const correctness", it's fundamental for C++.

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 When you are declaring any object you should default to using a `const` qualifier and ask yourself: "does it make sense for this object to be modified? if so remove the `const`. In this case you are not modifying `lhs` and `rhs` by comparing their values, so it doesn't make sense to make them non-const.

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 the object being passed is temp (`CompareTargetEnArray()`). As such it is lifetime-extended only via const-reference, and from that can only have `const` member functions accessible (since the object reference itself is `const`).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you, const correctness is broad topic and I am asking about particular reason why this solution posted above solves a problem

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you very much, this is what I wanted to know

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 no problem, and in case you didn't put it together yet, had the OP simply declared an *instance* of `CompareTargetEnArray mycmp;`, then passed `mycmp` as the third parameter, it would also have worked. If you followed my earlier comment it should make sense why.

Comment: @WhozCraig sure, and this should also be mentioned in an answer

Comment: @WhozCraig, Erm. The third argument is [passed by value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). No object lifetime is extended.